# Output the euro sign in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, encoding

I'm currently trying to output the euro symbol through a simple ruby script that I made but I keep getting "?" whenever I try.

I'm currently using puts "\244".

Any thoughts?

btw. I'm using ruby 1.9.2 p180

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a "**magic comment**" at the top of your script like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

puts "€"
```

... assuming that you want to use UTF-8 to allow for double-byte characters. You can then use the Euro symbol directly.

You can read more about Ruby 1.9 string encoding and magic comments here:

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings